# overflow:visible on SVG elements in Safari 7

Tags: css, svg, safari

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HRsvX/105/) I have an SVG with `overflow: visible` and a red triangle which protrudes outside the viewbox and is viewed in its entirety:

[image]

This works in Safari 8 and all other current browsers.

It does not work, however, in Safari 7:
[image]

Is there some sort of workaround for this? 
(Redefining both the SVG elements as well as the viewbox is not the option I'm looking for)

Comment: In that case, no. If you're not prepared to adjust the viewBox you need to admit defeat.

Comment: Wow.. that's such a downer.. :(